# Combine the value of two cells in the cell which is adjacent to Active cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine the content of two cells in one single cell. But the twist i want to put here is: I want the First value to go from..... where I already have somewhere in my sheet and the second value will go on runtime, whenever the Macro will be called. It means, I want my macro to pick the second value from ActiveCell. And then it will show the combined data of these two cells in the same row adjacent to my active cell.

Let's make it simpler by this example:

Assume that, I already have first value stored in "C2" and I want to combine this "C2" value with the second value. I just don't have my second value till now. And I want my Second value to go from the ActiveCell. Let's suppose my highlighted or ActiveCell is "A7". Is there a way to combine the content of this "A7" and "C2" cells together, and then show the combined content in the same row in the cell which is adjacent to my ActiveCell i.e., "A8" or "A6" wherever I want.

So far I have tried this to fulfill the requirement.

> Private Sub CombineTwoCells()
>
> Dim cell1 As String
>
> Dim cell2 As String
>
> Dim result As String
>
> Dim check As Range
>
> Do
>
> cell1 = "C2"
>
> Set check = Intersect(Range(cell1).Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells)
>
> Loop Until Not check Is Nothing
>
> Do
>
> cell2 = ActiveCell.Value
>
> Set result = Intersect(Range(cell2), ActiveSheet.Cells)
>
> Loop Until Not result Is Nothing
>
> Do
>
> result = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
>
> Set check = Intersect(Range(result), ActiveSheet.Cells)
>
> Loop Until Not check Is Nothing
>
> 'Cell1 has the address of cell "C2" and this statement below should put the result of combined content in adjacent to
> active cell

> Range(result) = Range(cell1) & Range(cell2)
>
> End Sub

Any sort of Suggestions or Code improvements are welcomed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to combine the value in the Activecell with the value in cell C2, try this:

```
Private Sub CombineTwoCells()
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("C2").Value & ActiveCell.Value
    
End Sub
```

If you want to cover each cell in your selection, try this:

```
Private Sub CombineTwoCellsRangeEdition()
    
    Dim RngCell As Range
    
    For Each RngCell In Selection
        RngCell.Offset(0, Selection.Columns.Count).Value = Range("C2").Value & RngCell.Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```